# How can i check vite meta instance is really original?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, environment-variables, vite

I use vite js env functionality. I want to check meta object is realy original.

For instance.

```
var meta = import meta;

console.log(instanceof meta MetaObject); true // false
```

Is there any way to do this ? Or how can i check the this object whether it is original ?

https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Comment: What do you mean by "*is original*"?

Comment: i just wonder if someone can change the properties of this object and i want to avoid it

Comment: You could try to [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) the object